# Autofocus not working ok when elem shows up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm not getting autofocus on the input when it shows up. 
The autofocus property works intermitently on Chrome. 
On IE11... well it does not even try to add it.

Do I need to validate the existence of the input element on the DOM before apply the autofocus with jQuery?

**HTML5**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" autofocus placeholder="Filter">
```

**JS**

```
   function iboxHistorySearch() {
        var header = $('.client-history .ibox-title_replace'),
            searchbar = $('.client-history .client-history-searchbar'),
            closeBtn = $('.client-history .btn-dismiss');

        header.on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (searchbar.hasClass('hidden')) {
                searchbar.removeClass('hidden')find('form-control:first').focus();
                $(this).addClass('hidden');
            }
        });

        closeBtn.on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (header.hasClass('hidden')) {
                header.removeClass('hidden');
                searchbar.addClass('hidden');
            }
        });
    }

    iboxHistorySearch();
```

**UPDATE**

```
searchbar.removeClass('hidden')find('form-control:first').focus();
```

Comment: Check, is https://jsfiddle.net/br3t/xbg5fyac/ correct example? Woks good for me.

Comment: Exactly which element are you trying to focus on?  '.client-history-searchbar' doesn't sound like an `input` and more like a div.  Did you mean `searchbar.removeClass('hidden').find('form-control:first').focus()` ?

Comment: @br3t too much speculation as to the html layout

Comment: @khanistopos you'll need to include your html, or better a full code snippet.  In the meantime, please read this [mcve]

Comment: According to the docs *"Take care to only use .focus() on elements that are visible"* - so you'll get an error rather than nothing and you'd need to check it's visible, not just exists.

Comment: @freedomn-m you was right. I was not targeting the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the (unedited) question:

```
var searchbar = $('.client-history .client-history-searchbar')

if (searchbar.hasClass('hidden')) {
    searchbar.removeClass('hidden').focus();
```

make sure that searchbar is an `input` control that can receive focus.  If not, add a `.find` to get an input, either the first or a specific element, eg:

```
    searchbar.removeClass('hidden')
             .find('.form-control:first')
             .focus();
```

or

```
    searchbar.removeClass('hidden')
             .find('input:first')
             .focus();
```

(but with `input` you may also need to add checkbox/select etc, eg)

```
    searchbar.removeClass('hidden')
             .find('input,select,textarea')
             .first()
             .focus();
```